# Add registry key via batchfile

Tags: windows, windows-registry, batch-file

I'm trying to create a registry key with a batch file.  I really need to be able to do this via a batch rather than a VBscript or .reg file.

So far by using this [guide](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc742162%28v=ws.10%29.aspx), I've come up with this. but whenever I try to run it, I don't see it in the registry. (No errors, running as Admin)  What am I doing wrong?

```
REG ADD HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\SpecialAccounts\UserList /v "MyCustomWorkgroupUsername" /t REG_DWORD /d 0
```

Comment: are you able to add the value manually, through regedit?
or else, you might not have permission to do so..

Comment: Yes, I've been able to create reg. values using everything but a batch file.

Comment: Found the issue.  Because there was a space in the subkey 'Windows NT', it was treating everything after that as parameters. Added quotations around my key fixed it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add quotation marks around the subkey

```
REG ADD "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\SpecialAccounts\UserList" /v "MyCustomWorkgroupUsername" /t REG_DWORD /d 0
```