# Issue writing batch file for a logon script to add registry entry at logon

Tags: windows, batch, windows-registry, login

This is the key I need to add during the login of a user.  We have no login scripts currently and I'm just losing it on how to make a batch file to do it.

This is extracted from the .reg file.  Is it possible to have this run with no admin rights or pop-ups?

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Terminal Server Client\Default\Addins\RDPAddins]
"Name"="C:\\Program Files\\NCR\\RDPAddins\\RDPAddins.Core.dll"
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add registry key via batchfile](https://superuser.com/questions/438153/add-registry-key-via-batchfile)

Comment: Are you in a domain environment? What version of Windows are you running (e.g. Windows 10 Enterprise)?